# Bevy / Winit - Open GUI Without Focus

Tags: windows, rust, focus, bevy, winit

I'm writing various graphical tests in Bevy. Each spawns the GUI, runs for a few seconds, and then exits the app and moves on to the next.

I love being able to visually check its doing what I think, but when each starts it steals focus from VS Code. This means I can't code while the tests are running, or use a 'hot-reload' workflow.

I understand that Bevy uses Winit under the hood, but couldn't find anything in either the [bevy plugin](https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/blob/main/crates/bevy_winit/src/lib.rs) or [Winit source](https://github.com/rust-windowing/winit) on opening a window without focus, or surrendering focus once it is open.

My ideal solution would be a simple setting in the `WindowDescriptor`:

```rust
App::new()
  .insert_resource(WindowDescriptor {
    
    // this would be awesome
    open_without_focus:true, 

    ..Default::default()
    })
  .run()
```

A few notes:

- I'm on Windows 11 but it would be great to have a platform agnostic solution.
- I have tried various Always On Top solutions like PowerToys but this doesn't help with focus.

Comment: For windows this was done with winit in a separate branch once here: https://github.com/rust-windowing/winit/commit/06fe019e63f5a0ab273f54ac4bc29b89c7683de3

Answer (score 1):

Not ideal, but am finding invoking `Alt+Escape` with [enigo](https://crates.io/crates/enigo) better than nothing:

```
use enigo::*;

pub fn surrender_focus(){
  let mut enigo = Enigo::new();
  enigo.key_down(Key::Alt);
  enigo.key_click(Key::Escape);
  enigo.key_up(Key::Alt);
}

fn main(){
  App::new()
    .add_startup_system(surrender_focus)
    .run()
}
```